# SQL COUNT FORM JOIN TABLES

Tags: sql, sql-server, derby

I have the following sql command:

```
SELECT "USERNAME"."TOPICS".VALUE,
       "USERNAME"."TOPICS".QID,
       "USERNAME"."QUESTION".QRATING
FROM "USERNAME"."TOPICS" JOIN "USERNAME"."QUESTION"
ON "USERNAME"."TOPICS".QID = "USERNAME"."QUESTION".QID 
AND "USERNAME"."TOPICS".VALUE = 'kia'
ORDER BY QRATING DESC
```

It works really well, but I want to count how many element returns.  So I tried to use:

```
SELECT COUNT("USERNAME"."TOPICS".QID)
FROM "USERNAME"."TOPICS" JOIN "USERNAME"."QUESTION"
ON "USERNAME"."TOPICS".QID = "USERNAME"."QUESTION".QID 
AND "USERNAME"."TOPICS".VALUE = 'kia'
ORDER BY QRATING DESC
```

But I get the error :

> Column reference 'USERNAME.TOPICS.VALUE' is invalid. When the SELECT
>   list contains at least one aggregate then all entries must be valid
>   aggregate expressions.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm.  The `ORDER BY` should be getting the error, not the `SELECT`.  However, your query would be much easier to understand using table aliases:

```
SELECT COUNT(t.QID)
FROM "USERNAME"."TOPICS" t JOIN
     "USERNAME"."QUESTION" q
     ON t.QID = q.QID AND t.VALUE = 'kia';
```

If the first query works, I see no reason why this would not (and your original without the `ORDER BY` should also work).